multiple datasources in springboot 3
I have working project with springboot 2, with 2 datasources configured as shown in here or here. I upgraded to springboot 3. All LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean,  DataSource, DataSourceProperties and PlatformTransactionManager remained the same. But when I run the project now, I'm getting:
PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: read-only
persistence provider classname: null
classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4e0e2f2a
excludeUnlistedClasses: true
JTA datasource: null
Non JTA datasource: net.ttddyy.dsproxy.support.ProxyDataSource@6f36267d
Transaction type: RESOURCE_LOCAL
PU root URL: file:…/target/classes/
Shared Cache Mode: UNSPECIFIED
Validation Mode: AUTO
Jar files URLs []
Managed classes names []
Mapping files names []
Properties []

Yes, if I create MWE in initializr, just put there spring.datasource.url = …, and otherwise rely on spring-magic, it will work.
Can someone advise what am I missing, what was changed in springboot 3 in configuring jpa, or what can I debug to find out why none jpa entity is discovered?
EDIT: So far I was able to get to this method, org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.PersistenceManagedTypesScanner#scan:
public PersistenceManagedTypes scan(String... packagesToScan) {
    ScanResult scanResult = new ScanResult();
    for (String pkg : packagesToScan) {
        scanPackage(pkg, scanResult);
    }
    return scanResult.toJpaManagedTypes();
}

in springboot2 the scanPackage discovered entities in given package, in springboot3 it does not find anything. This class is new in springboot 3 so either it requires something new in order to scan actually work, or it does not work.
EDIT 2: full configuration:
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("appname.datasource.main")
public DataSourceProperties mainDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
@Primary
public DataSource mainDataSource(ThreadQueryCountHolder threadQueryCountHolder,
                                 Environment environment,
                                 SqlFailedQueryExecutionListener sqlFailedQueryExecutionListener) {
    DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties = mainDataSourceProperties();

    HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = dataSourceProperties
            .initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();

    Binder.get(environment).bind("appname.datasource.main.hikari", Bindable.ofInstance(hikariDataSource));

    return wrapWithDataSourceProxy(dataSourceProperties,
            hikariDataSource,
            threadQueryCountHolder,
            sqlFailedQueryExecutionListener);
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = MAIN_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY)
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mainEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                       ThreadQueryCountHolder threadQueryCountHolder,
                                                                       SpringJpaConfigProperties springJpaConfigProperties,
                                                                       Environment environment,
                                                                       SqlFailedQueryExecutionListener sqlFailedQueryExecutionListener,
                                                                       DefaultListableBeanFactory defaultListableBeanFactory) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = builder
            .dataSource(mainDataSource(threadQueryCountHolder, environment, sqlFailedQueryExecutionListener))
            .packages(PredictorResultEntity.class, SelfieEntity.class)
            .build();

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(springJpaConfigProperties.getHibernateProperties());
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.getJpaPropertyMap().put(AvailableSettings.BEAN_CONTAINER, new SpringBeanContainer(defaultListableBeanFactory));

    return em;
}

@Primary
@Bean(MAIN_TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
public PlatformTransactionManager mainTransactionManager(@Qualifier(MAIN_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY)
                                                                     LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mainEntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(mainEntityManagerFactory.getObject()));
}

@Primary
@Bean(MAIN_JDBC_TEMPLATE)
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(ThreadQueryCountHolder threadQueryCountHolder,
                                 Environment environment,
                                 SqlFailedQueryExecutionListener sqlFailedQueryExecutionListener) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(mainDataSource(threadQueryCountHolder, environment,
            sqlFailedQueryExecutionListener));
}

@Bean
public ThreadQueryCountHolder threadQueryCountHolder() {
    return new ThreadQueryCountHolder();
}



private static DataSource wrapWithDataSourceProxy(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties,
                                                  DataSource dataSource,
                                                  ThreadQueryCountHolder threadQueryCountHolder,
                                                  SqlFailedQueryExecutionListener sqlFailedQueryExecutionListener) {
    return ProxyDataSourceBuilder.create(dataSource)
            .asJson()
            .logSlowQueryBySlf4j(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, SLF4JLogLevel.WARN, "SlowSql")
            .name(dataSourceProperties.getName())
            .countQuery(threadQueryCountHolder)
            .logQueryBySlf4j(SLF4JLogLevel.DEBUG)
            .listener(sqlFailedQueryExecutionListener)
            .build();
}

EDIT 3: pom.xml inherits from spring parent:
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

and only dependencies are:
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
</dependency>


The information provided is far too little to give you any help. There is no configuration (neither properties nor classes), no stacktrace etc. Just some weird output. Nothing changed in regards to configuring datasources etc.

@M.Deinum I do understand that. I would like to add something specific, yet I don't have it. The question is about what can I enable, to be able to see ANY explanation. Btw. Please see update in question. I'm still working on it, trying to find any interesting information, why scan did not work as intended.

You are shooting blanks and wide here. You haven't described what isn't working, you haven't shown your configuration etc. You are now putting in everything you find, that is not how this works. You also mention an upgrade add your pom.xml or build.gradle to your question as well (it wouldn't be the first one using too many dependencies trying to outsmart the Spring Boot dependency management and leading to issues).

@M.Deinum the configurations are shown in 2 tutorials I linked. What does not work is scanning process, which does not discover jpa entities which are indeed there.

I don't care about the tutorials, I care about your configuration and dependencies.

@M.Deinum understood, I'm adding it to question. And yes, PersistenceManagedTypesScanner is new class, so this scanner is not used in springboot 2.

Entities not being detected my guess outsmarting dependency management and having an incompatible persistence-api and entities still ulsing javax.persistence instead of jakarta.persistence.

all javax.persistence was replaced, not sure what outsmarting could I have done (it's possible, sure). Added maven dependencies.

The this.componentsIndex used in that method/class seems unintialized sufficiently, that map does not contain any "package-info" or "interface jakarta.persistence.Entity". (and it's deprecated-for-removal already ...)

One thing that is, imho, wrong is your overriding of the JpaVendorAdapter you should remove that. The SpringBeanContainer is already set in the builder. To add the properties use the properties method on the builder and return the factory as is from the builder. I highly doubt the problem is in the class you are looking at else others would have already reported this as this is used by a massive user base. The issue is somewhere in your code/setup. I still suspect using the wrong @Entity or missing it or something alike.

I understand your point, thanks for recommendation, will check. Yet it works in 2.x, and I updated javax->jakarta. In not aware of any other change needed in entities which could make them undiscoverable... Thats why I asked for finest logs showing what is (not) happening... If the question is not closed, I will post solution ;) Regarding massive user base: happened to me few times that I found there(and got confirmed) a bug, which completely disabled some scenario.

@M.Deinum I was SO close yesterday! Comparing with application generated by initializr I found out, that both takes different path during scanning process, and was able to find out and confirm, that difference was caused by org.springframework:spring-context-indexer:5.3.20 This dependency had for some reason specified version instead of being taken from bom, so it wasn't updated in process, and I overlooked it. So you was correct, it was outsmarted dependency management. Will write it down as answer.

Cause of not seeing entities in my case was using
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-indexer</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.20</version>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

this was part of project, and I overlooked during upgrade, that this dependency versino was not taken from BOM. Thus it wasn't updated. It kinda worked, but generated caches was corrupted, which was the reason why no entities was discovered.
